# Horizontal alignment of text blocks

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I want two text blocks in a horizontal row. In the middle between them, there should be an arrow pointing from left to right.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

As you see, the arrow is not in the middle between the two text blocks. That's something I want to achieve.

Right now I'm using minipages with fixed width to achieve the result above.

```
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := X + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
  \centering $\Rightarrow$
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := 3 + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
```

But with that solution I would have to adjust the absolute width of the minipages until the text fits inside. That's not a clean solution though, because when I change the text size (or anything else related to the font) everything will break.

Is there a clean solution to horizontally align the two text blocks, with an arrow in the middle between them, and with adjustable whitespace between the blocks and the arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := X + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\hfill $\Rightarrow$ \hfill
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := 3 + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note that the arrow seem not centered because the space not filled in minipages. For a better results you can use `varwidth` package instead of `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := X + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{varwidth}%
\hfill$\Rightarrow$\hfill%
\begin{varwidth}{.2\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
X := 3
Y := Z * W
Q := X + Y
\end{verbatim}
\end{varwidth}
\hfill
\end{document}
```

Using `\dotfill` instead of `\hfill` you can check visually that both block are reaally equally spaced.

[image: MWE]

Note: Be careful of remove spaces around `\hfill` (thanks to David to note the lack of ending `%`).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve the problem. If I use `{.4\textwidth}` as width for the blocks, the arrow is not centered at all.

Comment: @DaniloBargen, please see the edited answer.

Comment: The OP wanted it centred on the longest lines of the text, but note this does not center between the minipages either, the space to the left of the arrow is one word space (3.333pt) more than the space to the right as you are missing a `%` after `\end{minipage}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I always forget the ending `%`. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Works great now. And with using `\hspace` instead of `\hfill` I can control the exact space between the arrow and the blocks.

Comment: use of `varwidth` definitely better than the clumsy thing I did in my answer with a `tabular`; will remove my answer which is not useful.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments.

[image]

If a `minipage` contains `tabbing` it is just as wide as the widest tabbing row. Don't forget the `%`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}\ttfamily
\begin{tabbing}
X := 3\\
Y := Z * W\\
Q := X + Y
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill $\Rightarrow$\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}\ttfamily
\begin{tabbing}
X := 3\\
Y := Z * W\\
Q := 3 + Y
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `{\centering\hfill<your stuff>\hfill\null\par}` the thing is less spread out on the line.

Comment: it is not in my testing... another point: rather than `\hfill$\Rightarrow$\hfill` a `\makebox` or `minipage` as in OP allows user control on the inner spaces. And then `\centering` suffices with no `\hfill`'s.

Comment: @jfbu I can also control the inner space by using `\hspace` instead of `\hfill`. @David Carisle: Yes, I'll try to post complete examples next time :)

Comment: @DaniloBargen right, but with a `\makebox` you control better the positions of the left and right blocks on the line as you don't have to estimate the width of the right arrow.

Comment: @jfbu: Yes, true.

Comment: @jfbu (sorry indentation box saves the hfill, I removed the comment) yes OP isn't clear what final intention is, there are lots of more direct ways to adjust the space, eg change `\hfill` to `\hspace{3pt plus 100}` will mean that there is at least 3pt and at most 103pt space.

Comment: I didn't at all know about this `\hspace{3pt plus 100}` construct! (and didn't know about tabbing either...)

Comment: @jfbu I'm out of edit time but the above comment should be `3pt plus 100pt` I seem to have omitted the units of the plus component

Comment: ah, thanks, `3pt plus 100pt`, makes sense, standard glue specifier.